# Convert simple array to new data structure using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

I have the following array in PHP:

```
{
    "roles_id": "1",
    "assessments_id": "1",
    "question_id_1": "1",
    "radio_id_1": "1",
    "question_id_2": "2",
    "radio_id_2": "5",
    "question_id_3": "3",
    "radio_id_3": "9"
}
```

I want to create a data structure with this data just like the example below:

```
[
    {
        "user_roles_id": "1",
        "hidden_courses_assessments_id": "1",
        "hidden_question_id_1": "1",
        "radio_id_1": "1",
        "question_id_2": "2"
    },
    {
        "user_roles_id": "1",
        "hidden_courses_assessments_id": "1",
        "hidden_question_id_1": "1",
        "radio_id_2": "2",
        "question_id_2": "5"
    },
    {
        "user_roles_id": "1",
        "hidden_courses_assessments_id": "1",
        "hidden_question_id_1": "1",
        "radio_id_3": "3",
        "question_id_3": "9"
    }
]
```

The two elements are always the same, but the others are separated after every two elements.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why is `"hidden_question_id_1":"1"` in every subarray?

Comment: `array_shift` twice then `array_chunk` on 2 and then loop and build new array changing the key names.

Comment: @u_mulder this is the response that I get from the server

Comment: `hidden_question_id_` __does not__ present in first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, extract two elements from array, and split the rest of array into chunks of size 2:

```php
$s = '{"roles_id":"1", "assessments_id":"1", "question_id_1":"1", "radio_id_1":"1","question_id_2":"2", "radio_id_2":"5", "question_id_3":"3", "radio_id_3":"9"}';

$a = json_decode($s, true);
$baseData = [
    "user_roles_id" => array_shift($a), 
    "hidden_courses_assessments_id" => array_shift($a),
    // I don't know what's this values so I just put it here
    "hidden_question_id_1" => "1",
];
$result = [];
    
$key = 1;
foreach (array_chunk($a, 2) as $chunk) {
    $result[] = array_merge($baseData, ["radio_id_$key" => $chunk[0], "question_id_$key" => $chunk[1]]);
    
    ++$key;
}
print_r($result);  // apply `json_encode` if needed
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/P44ae).